# Counter in a do while loop in C

Tags: c, loops, counter, do-while

I am trying to keep a count of how many times the operation inside the do-while loop is repeating, but the counter only shows 1 each time. Can anyone tell me where is my mistake? I have provided the code here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double i = 84;
    int counter = 0;
    do {
        counter++;
        i = fmod(i, 25.0);

        }
    while(i > 25);
    printf("Counter: %i\n %lf\n", counter, i);
}
```

Comment: What else did you expect? `fmod` will bring `i` to less than `84` in first iteration.

Comment: Please don't tag C++ and C, they are different languages. Next take a debugger, run the code line by line and watch how the variables change. That will give you exact understanding on what's happening there.

Answer (score 2):

`fmod` is floating point modulo.

It cannot return something higher than `25.0` since you've passed `25.0` as the modulo value.

That's why `while(i>25)` is false at the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = fmod(i, 25.0);
```

This takes the current value of `i` and finds the remainder of its division by 25. Following that, the remainder is reassigned to `i`.

```
double i = 84;
```

This sets the initial value of `i` to 84. If we do `84 % 25`, we get `9.0`. And since `9.0 < 25.0`, the loop will terminate after the first operation. Therefore, `counter` is only incremented once in your loop.